# Cancel / Exit HP System Recovery Manager (Windows Vista)

Tags: windows-vista, system-recovery, recovery-partition

I started the HP System Recovery Manager inadvertently (by hitting F11 during the boot sequence) and am now unable to exit the tool.

I do not need or want to run a full recovery or reset the PC to the factory settings. Rather, I just want to exit the System Recovery Manager so that I'm again able to boot normally into Vista.

I have not actually started the recovery process, it seems I've just set a bit that forces the PC to boot into the Recovery Manager, and I have, so far, been unable to unset that bit to get back to the standard boot process.

No matter what I do, every time I restart or reboot the PC, it always boots straight into the recovery mode. I have tried cancelling the recovery operation a couple of different ways with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talk about obscure. I had purchased this HP PC almost 3 years ago to replace an even older HP PC.

I had installed the hard drive from the older PC into this newer one as a secondary hard drive, so I could have access to the files on it. I'd forgotten that fact in the interim.

The problem occurred because I had started the HP Recovery process on the older drive, somehow, and it wasn't being disabled when I tried to cancel out of the process. I used the diskpart command line utility to figure out and fix the problem. First, I used it to find out which partition was active. Sure enough, the active partition was the recovery partition on the older drive. I then used the same utility to mark that partition inactive, and mark the main partition on the newer drive active.

The next time I booted up, everything worked perfectly (the PC booted into Windows Vista). I promptly made a copy of the user data on the older drive, then reformatted that drive to make sure this could never happen again.